# How to make google return search results based on some foreign location? (without proxy)

Tags: http, request, google-search

As far as I know Google determines my location by the IP address. So, when I do a search request (let say, using curl) I'm getting results based on the server location. Is there a way to make google return results based on some other location? (I can't use proxy in my situation)

There is an ability to set a different region using browser in the google setting like this:

1.[image: google settings select]
2.[image: google settings regions]

When I set some other region I get results based on it:
[image: current location results]
[image: German results]

**I need to achieve the same behavior without using a browser. Is there any additional things(headers, cookies...) that I need to send in the HTTP request to let google know that I want results based on a different region?**

Answer (score 0):

Think, you can open search query which you need on the mobile phone, phisical device or emulated, with driver like Appium. You can also change location before executing a search.